# How to store checkbox checked Values in ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to store the checkbox checked values of `ExpandableListView` child in array list but I am unable to do this. The `ArrayList` only gives me the last checked value but I want to store all the checked values of checkbox.

```
package com.zobrando.contests;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;


public class RightDrawerListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
String xid;
private List<String> navDrawerItems;
private ArrayList<RightNanDrawerItems> childItems;
HashMap<String, List<String>> popuplist;
boolean checkBoxStates[];

HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> mChildCheckStates = new HashMap<Integer,     boolean[]>();
private static final Integer[] Icons = {
        R.drawable.trophy,
        R.drawable.buld,
        R.drawable.brand,
        R.drawable.target,
        R.drawable.age,
        R.drawable.participants,
        R.drawable.reward
};
CheckBox checkBox;

public RightDrawerListAdapter(Context context, List<String>   navDrawerItems,HashMap<String, List<String>> popuplist){
    this.context = context;
    this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    this.childItems = childItems;
    this.popuplist = popuplist;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int chlidPosition) {
    //String pos = String.valueOf(groupPosition);
    return this.popuplist.get(this.navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition))
            .get(chlidPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

    return this.navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {

    return this.navDrawerItems.size();
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

 @Override
 public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
 }

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup  parent) {

    final String childText = getChild(groupPosition,      childPosition).toString();
    final ArrayList<String> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_list_items,  null);
    }
    //selectedStrings.clear();

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.popuplist);
    checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checked);

    //checkBox.setText(childid);
    txtTitle.setText(childText);

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new     CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean   isChecked) {
                     if (isChecked){
                        xid = childText.substring(0,1);
                        xid = xid.replace("-", "");
                        selectedStrings.add(xid);
                    }

                Toast.makeText(context,xid+"xid",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context,selectedStrings+"Seleted   Strings",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                               
                SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString("xid", mChildCheckStates+"");
                editor.apply();
        }
    });
    //checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new   CheckchangeListener(groupPosition));
    return convertView;
}


@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.popuplist.get(this.navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle =  getGroup(groupPosition).toString();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView =    infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.right_drawer_list_items, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    imgIcon.setImageResource(Icons[groupPosition]);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition).getIcon());
    txtTitle.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

class CheckchangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener     {
    private int position;


    public CheckchangeListener(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.position= position;


    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (isChecked) {
            //updateyour list and database here

        } else {
            //updateyour list and database here

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is that: selectedStrings.add(0,xid); ???

Comment: selectedStrings in an array list of String Type and i am adding xid at index 0

Comment: i also did like
xid = childText.substring(0,1);
                        xid = xid.replace("-", "");
                        selectedStrings.add(xid);

Comment: so you have added it in an arraylist... sounds good. what is the problem exactly?

Comment: i want add all the checked values of checkbox in array list but it only give me one value in array list

Comment: it gives last checked value not all

Comment: where did you declared selectedStrings. is it a class member? post the whole class please

Comment: Yes it is a class member sir, it is declared on top of the class, the only problem I am facing is that when i toast the arraylist it only have one last checked value, where as i want all the checked value to add in my arraylist

Comment: please help me as i am unable to do this

Comment: you have to post the whole class.

Comment: i have edited my code and added whole class @Stefan

Comment: remove global declaration of CheckBox checkBox; and put that inside getChildView. Like this CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checked);

Answer (score 0):

Do not declare `checkBox` and `xid` globally. Insted declare them inside `getChildView`.

You are getting only last value in your array-list because you declare your string globally.

So your `getChildView` code will look something like below :

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup  parent) {

    final String childText = getChild(groupPosition,      childPosition).toString();
    final ArrayList<String> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_list_items,  null);
    }
    //selectedStrings.clear();

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.popuplist);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checked);

    //checkBox.setText(childid);
    txtTitle.setText(childText);

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new     CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean   isChecked) {
                     if (isChecked){
                        String  xid = childText.substring(0,1);
                        xid = xid.replace("-", "");
                        selectedStrings.add(xid);
                    }

                Toast.makeText(context,xid+"xid",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context,selectedStrings+"Seleted   Strings",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                               
                SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString("xid", mChildCheckStates+"");
                editor.apply();
        }
    });
    //checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new   CheckchangeListener(groupPosition));
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...actually i was declaring selectedStrings final that was the issue